# Encrypt / Decrypt uidata with "homemade" algorithm

Tags: objective-c, image, encryption, cryptography

Just working on a algorithm and so far i can encrypt and decrypt a number, which works fine. My question now is how do i go abouts encrypting an image? How does the UIdata look and shold i convert the image to that before I start? Never done anything on this level in terms of encryption and any input would be great! Thanks!

Comment: I hope this is just for fun and you don't expect it to be secure.

Comment: for now it is. but why wouldnt it be secure? and what do u get out of giving me comments like that? are u here just for fun or do u want to get anything out of it?

Comment: It requires quite some cryptographic knowledge to build a secure encryption algorithm (and not just one which you can't break yourself). And if you have to ask such questions, you obviously don't have the knowledge. So, for a real life application, you would instead use standard algorithms (like AES with a secure mode of operation).

Comment: trust me, it wont be used to protect any of your or anyone elses private information. and why does that issue keeping you from helping me instead of just pointing out the obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to encrypt in small chunks - perhaps a byte or word/int (4 bytes), maybe even a long (8 bytes) at a time depending on how your algorithm is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the signature of your algorithm (i.e. what types of input it takes and what types output it gives), but the most common ciphers are *[block ciphers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher)*, i.e. algorithms which have a input of some block size (nowadays 128 bits = 16 bytes is a common size), and a same-sized output, additionally to a key input (which should also have at least 128 bits).

To encrypt longer pieces of data (and actually, also for short pieces if you send multiple such pieces with the same key), you use a [mode of operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation) (and probably additionally a padding scheme). This gives you an algorithm (or a pair of such) with an arbitrary length plaintext input, and slightly bigger ciphertext output (which the decryption algorithm undoes then).

Some hints:

- Don't use ECB mode (i.e. simply encrypting each block independently of the others).
- Probably you also should apply a MAC, to protect your data against malicious modifications (and also breaking of the encryption scheme by choosen-ciphertext attacks). Some modes of operation already include a MAC.